# Did 295 of Marsh & McLennan employees die in the World Trade Center during 9/11?

Tags: 9-11

According to Wikipedia, [Paul Bremer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Bremer) was

> Before rejoining government in 2003, he was chairman and CEO of Marsh Crisis Consulting, a risk and insurance services firm which is a subsidiary of Marsh & McLennan Companies.[citation needed]
>
> [...]
>
> Bremer and 1,700 of the employees of Marsh & McLennan had offices in the World Trade Center. Bremer's office was in the North Tower. In an interview with CNN after the September 11 attacks, he stated that their office was located "above where the second aircraft hit". On September 11, he was interviewed in Washington on WRC-TV at 12:30pm in-studio.

The referenced [September 14 2001 CNN Interview](http://edition.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/0109/14/cf.00.html) (which refers to him by his [nickname](https://worldteamsports.org/2010/paul-jerry-bremer/), "Jerry") cites him as saying

> We don't have final numbers yet. But we've obviously lost several hundreds of employees in this attack.

The [Marsh and McLennan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsh_%26_McLennan_Companies) wikipedia page cite [
[their web-site](http://memorial.mmc.com/) which says:

> On September 11, 2001, 295 colleagues and 63 consultants working in our offices were lost in the terrorist attacks on the World Trade Center.

(An [NBC interview on September 11, 2001](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2pW6WZhZrQ) is also available.)

Did 295 employees Marsh & McLellan employees lose their lives on that day?

Comment: I found good evidence on the losses of life; do you doubt Mr. Bremer's involvement with the company as well?

Comment: It is hard to believe. I was curious if there is any source where he personally mentions the fact. Also, have anyone asked him why he was not in the office at that day and went into several TV stations to provide interview?

Comment: I recommend you rephrase question and title, then, as it's not quite clear what exactly you're asking....

Comment: I am asking exactly what is in the title. There are many false claims concerning 9/11. Wanted to know if this one is true.

Comment: There's nothing "exact" about the title. Did 295 employees of MMC die? Yes. Did 295 *coworkers* of Paul Bremer die? Would that be still a "yes" if he'd been working for / with a different company? And your comment just now is asking about whether or not he, personally, made that claim. So I am asking again, *what exactly is your question*?

Comment: Your answer was good. You did not have to delete it. The wikipedia article has citation missing.

Comment: Well, Wikipedia was all the source I needed to piece together what's in the answer, actually. It might have been one or two clicks removed, but still. I undeleted my answer and flagged it Community Wiki so others might add the confirmation of Mr. Bremer's involvement with MMC.

Comment: I'm voting to close for now. It's not clear what the question is. Is it that Bremer was a CEO of Marsh & McLennan? If so, is that a notable claim? The linked wiki article at least doesn't claim so (instead saying that "he was chairman and CEO of Marsh Crisis Consulting, a risk and insurance services firm which is a subsidiary of Marsh & McLennan Companies").

Comment: I changed the question. Still the question stands. if his employees died.

Comment: Still a lot of blur. Now they have to be "his employees", not just his coworkers? What if his position at the time was a consulting one? Does it matter whether *he* held an office there? *What, exactly, are you doubting?* (Voting to close as well, now.)

Comment: If he was CEO of a subsidiary, they were his coworkers.

Comment: **What are you doubting? Exactly?** Whether he was CEO? Whether he was employed at all? Whether that particular company lost life? Come on. Right now your question could just as well end in "Discuss." Ask **one** question.

Comment: I doubting the whole claim that he worked in the North Tower, the only source is a transcript of an interview with some Jerry Bremer. Is he the same preson? Is there a video with Paul Bremer, where he talks about it?

Comment: It is unlikely that CNN would interview some *other* "former chairman of the Nation Commission on Terrorism" named "Bremer". Interestingly, the transcript is talking about the *south* tower, but I'll let that slide. I do not see anything that claims that Mr. Bremer himself held an office in either tower. When the host inquired about "your office", he could just as well be talking about "your company's office".

Comment: It's hard to see where the line is here between *clarifying* and *answering* an unclear question. I've edit it to show that Jerry is his nickname, to link to the CNN interview, to find a source of "295" number the OP quoted from nowhere, and to focus on whether the number they gave was true. If you mean "Did he work for Marsh & McLellan?" we should change the title.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Well, that's tailoring the question to match the answer. I figured the OP was more interested in the person of Mr. Bremer. I _assume_ this is because Bremer received a lot of criticism in 9/11 conspiracy circles, and the OP wants to know whether he did put himself in a more favorable light by associating himself with victims of the day. But since the OP didn't come out and said as much, all we have is guesswork, with the confirmed numbers of MMC casualties about the only reliable thing.

Comment: Oddthinking changed the question.

Comment: I've put it on hold, why we work out what the actual claim is. "Is Jerry the nickname of Paul?" seems silly; it doesn't take much effort to show that. Is it "Did 295 members of the company die?" Is it "Did Bremer work for the company?"

Comment: So, Bremer did not work in the WTC? You claim he did not in your previous comment. Do you have source for it?

Comment: @gavriel: Oddthinking is, like myself, trying to point out that your question was rather poorly phrased, as it remained unclear what, exactly, you were doubtful of. Perhaps re-think, and post a new question aiming specifically at whether Mr. Bremer held an office with Marsh. Note that top-level executives like that very frequently do *not* spend their day in a specific office in a specific building, so make sure you distinguish between holding an office -- i.e., be in a certain position in a company's hierarchy -- and *having* an office, the thing with a desk and a chair. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**Did 295 employees of Marsh & McLennan Companies lose their lifes as a result of 9/11?**

*Yes.*

The company has erected a memorial for the 295 employees (and 63 consultants), both in real life and [online](https://memorial.mmc.com). (Also, [this message from MMC Chairman Jeff Greenberg](https://web.archive.org/web/20010926154507/http://marsh.com/) regarding the deaths, located in the Wayback Machine of archive.org.)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsh_%26_McLennan_Companies#September_11_attacks) tells us their offices were on the floors 93 through 100 of the North Tower. The impact zone of the airplane was floors 93 through 99...

(The source for this is given as "Dwyer, Jim and Flynn, Kevin, 102 Minutes: The Untold Story of the Fight to Survive Inside the Twin Towers, Times Books, 2006, p. 19", but I am sure office locations could be verified otherwise with relative ease. I see no reason to doubt this.)

**Was Paul Bremer holding an office with Marsh & McLennan at that time?**

t.b.d.

Comment: I was more interested to Bremer's relation to the victims. And if he actually worked in the WTC office. But the question was changed completely by @Oddthinking.